# Why cant I filter my javascript/jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a javascript object array that looks like this:

```
[
{"fname":"tim", "lname":"thompson", "user_id": "2", "route_id": "3", "route_day": "WED"},
{"fname":"john", "lname":"wilson", "user_id": "3", "route_id": "3", "route_day": "WED"},
{"fname":"george", "lname":"lane", "user_id": "5", "route_id": "2", "route_day": "MON"}
]
```

I tried to filter out the results using the filter function

```
function filterCustomerData(route,day) {

    var jsonCustData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("db")); 

    console.dir(jsonCustData); // object array with 300+ objects
    console.log( "route is: " + route + " day is: " + day);// route is: 3 day is: WED

    var routes = jsonCustData.filter(function(ele, ind,arr){
        return ele.route_id == route && ele.route_day == day;
    });

    console.dir(routes); // Array[0]


    fillCustomerData(routes);
}
```

but everytime I do that I get an empty array. I know I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

EDIT: Again sorry for my mistake, I entered the full function this time.

Comment: JS is case sensitive, `route_day` != `Route_day`

Comment: also `ele.route_id = "3"` should be `ele.route_id == "3"`

Comment: The answer is in @RoryMcCrossan comment

Comment: Sorry for the mistake guys but the syntactical error are not really the problem. Those came about because I was in a rush to type this out.

Comment: @user3314802, then what is the problem? The snippet in my answer is working. Is there another problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `==` instead of `=`
2. Use `Route_day` instead of `route_day`

```js
var objArr = [
{"fname":"tim", "lname":"thompson", "user_id": "2", "route_id": "3", "Route_day": "WED"},
{"fname":"john", "lname":"wilson", "user_id": "3", "route_id": "3", "Route_day": "WED"},
{"fname":"george", "lname":"lane", "user_id": "5", "route_id": "2", "Route_day": "MON"}
];

var newobj = objArr.filter(function(ele, ind, arr){
  console.log(ele);
    return ele.route_id == "3" && ele.Route_day == "WED";
});

console.log(newobj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing an equal operator and your object property name is wrong "Route_day":

```
var newobj = obj.filter(function(ele, ind, arr){
    return ele.route_id === "3" && ele.route_day === "WED";
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is in the key. `Route_day !== route_day`